# Do Erlang timers scale?

Tags: timer, erlang

In my websocket server developed with Erlang, I would like to use a timer (`start_timer/3`), for each connection, to terminate the connection if the timeout elapses without receiving a "ping" from the client.

Do Erlang timers scale well, assuming I will have a large number of client connestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is a large number of connections? Erlangs VM uses a timer wheel internally to handle the timers so it scales pretty well up to some thousand connections. Then you might run into trouble.

Usually the trick is to group pids together on timers. This is also what kernels tend to do. If for instance you have a timer that has to awake in 200ms you schedule yourself ahead of time not on the next, but the next 200ms timer again. This means you will wait at least 200ms and perhaps 400ms, 300ms being typical. By approximating timers like this, you are able to run many more since you can have a single timer wake up large numbers of processes in one go. But depending on the timer frequency and amounts of timers a standard `send_after/3` may be enough.

In any case, I would start by assuming it can scale and then handle the problem if it can't by doing approximate timing like envisioned above.

Answer (score 0):

A usual pattern for this kind of server is to take advantage of the light weight Erlang processes, and create a server per connection.

You can build for example your server using a gen_server behavior that provide you both

- the different state to manage the connection (waiting for a connection, login,...) with the State variable,
- individual timeout for each connection and at each state, managed by the VM and the OTP behavior.

The nice thing is that each server has to take care of a single client, so it is really easier to write.

The init phase should launch one server waiting for connection,

Then on connection the server should launch a new one ready for next client (ideally through a supervisor launching simple_one_for_one child) and go to login step or whatever you want to do.

You will find very interesting information on the site LearnYouSomeErlang, particularly in the chapter http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors and the following ones.